# How to merge multiple update clause into single update clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE limestone_sub_test (
    sub_id            NUMBER(10),
    limestone_id      NUMBER(10),
    sub_status_id     NUMBER(10),
    limestone_prg_id  NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_sub_id_test PRIMARY KEY ( sub_id )
);

INSERT INTO limestone_sub_test values(1,33,38,1);
INSERT INTO limestone_sub_test values(2,33,39,1);
INSERT INTO limestone_sub_test values(3,33,42,1);
INSERT INTO limestone_sub_test values(4,33,43,1);
INSERT INTO limestone_sub_test values(5,33,44,1);
INSERT INTO limestone_sub_test values(6,33,45,1);
INSERT INTO limestone_sub_test values(7,33,46,1);

commit;
```

My Attempt :
First Update

```
UPDATE limestone_sub
SET
    limestone_prg_id =
        CASE
            WHEN limestone_prg_id = 1  THEN
                2
            WHEN limestone_prg_id = 2  THEN
                3
            ELSE
                3
        END
WHERE
        limestone_id = 33
    AND sub_status_id = 38;
```

I need to update limestone_prg_id to 2 where sub_status_id = 38

Second Update:

```
UPDATE limestone_sub SET limestone_prg_id =
case
    WHEN 
        limestone_prg_id in(SELECT
            limestone_prg_id
        FROM
            limestone_sub
        WHERE
                sub_status_id = 38
            AND limestone_prg_id = 2)
     THEN
        1
        WHEN limestone_prg_id IN(
    SELECT
        limestone_prg_id
    FROM
        limestone_sub
    WHERE
            sub_status_id = 38
        AND limestone_prg_id = 3
) THEN 2
    end
WHERE
        limestone_id = 33
    AND sub_status_id = 39;
```

I am checking if the limestone_prg_id is 2 or 3 for sub_status_id = 38 If it is 2 then I need to update limestone_prg_id = 1 where sub_status_id = 39 and if it is 2 then update limestone_prg_id = 2 where sub_status_id = 39.

Likewise, I will check until 46 sub_status_id but can it be done in a single update query instead of writing multiple update queries and also my second update is updating null value for sub_status_id 39. But ideally, it should update to 1

My output :
[image: My output where it is updating null which is not expected]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again; edit and improve [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70306522/266304). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). (And also please show all code, data and results as formatted text, [not as images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).)

Comment: @AlexPooleSure will edit the same question. And for images how will I be able to create a table while asking the question so I used excel and sniped it

Comment: @AlexPoole I have edited the same question but how to close this thread?

Comment: You can use [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) to create good looking text tables. Run your query then copy results, column titles included, (or create a tab separated list) and past it into the input area; click `create table` and copy the output box. Now create 2 lines in your question containng nothing but ```. Paste the above results between them.